# How to Multicast audio stream on my laptop - MAC-OSX - Mavericks - the source and destination is same here?

Tags: network, macos, vlc

I am using VLC to multicast an audio stream - song on my OS-X mavericks. I need multicasting streaming only here. However, I cannot hear the audio. The volume level of my machine is fine. Looks, like the audio streaming or receiving is not working.

Here are the steps that I did to setup a multicast streaming.  I am streaming a MP3 song.

a. [image]

b. [image]

c. [image]

d. [image]

e. [image]

f. [image]

g. [image]

h. [image]

---

Receiver Setup -

Again on the same pc - I opened the VLC-- following options --

1. [image]
2. [image]
3. [image]
4. [image]
5. [image]

Now, in order to confirm that I am streaming, I checked on a wireshark. I am on a wifi interface.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Note that VLC does not support streaming from live video or audio sources on Mac OSX